# r: package arm: error when loading: Functions found when exporting methods from the namespace ‘arm’ which are not S4 generic: ‘fixef’, ‘ranef’

Tags: r, arm, lme4

```
> library(arm)
Loading required package: lme4
Loading required package: RcppEigen
Loading required package: R2WinBUGS
Loading required package: foreign
Error : Functions found when exporting methods from the namespace ‘arm’ which are not S4 generic: ‘fixef’, ‘ranef’
Error: package/namespace load failed for ‘arm’
```

maybe relevant: 
R version is 2.15.3. 
arm version is 1.6-05.
lme4 version is 0.99999911-1. 
I did run update.packages() before posting.

I am currently wondering if the latest version of arm and lme4 are not compatible. I want to use the predict.mermod() function in the new lme4 but I also rely on arm when using lme4. I tried loading arm with lme4 detached but lme4 is a required package for arm so that did not work either. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Should this be directed to the maintainer of `arm`?

Comment: For what it's worth, `install.packages('arm'); library(arm)` works under R-3.0.0. perhaps `update.packages()` will get a working installation?

Comment: I see the current version is 1.6-05. So maybe the version specs in the package are wrong (or update.packages was not run with checkBuilt=TRUE) or Mariana is trying to load a package compiled for r3.0.0 into R 2.15.3?

Comment: Thank you for helping! I did run update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE) but, in addition, I have updated lme4 with the newer r-forge version in order to get predict.mermod(). I don't believe I am running R3.0 packages in 2.15.3. lme4 loads without errors and arm does not complain about the R version.

Comment: I use 2.15.3 and a fresh install of arm, and it works just fine.

Comment: Hint: what about `sessionInfo()` / starting in a clean R session, possibly with `--vanilla`?  In particular, did you have `nlme` loaded prior to trying this? (Although I can't replicate even when loading `nlme` first ...)

Answer (score 1):

The current version of `arm` is not compatible with the development version of `lme4` from R-forge/GitHub.
I presume `arm` still expects `lme4` to produce `mer` classes, instead of the new `merMod` ones.

(Side note: The latest `car` from R-forge (2.0-19) does support `merMod` classes for e.g. Anova(), I found out today (just in case you need it))

Comment: See also http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/misc/pkgtests/lme4_compat_report.html -- I believe a few package maintainers have private, fixed versions that they plan to release when `lme4`-stable is released.